# Given a point, create a triangle with it through shaders in Stride

Tags: shaders, stride

Need help in writing shaders in Stride.
I have a vertex list. I need to create triangle from each of the vertex. For each vertex, it will be considered as a center point and three new points are calculated around it. Now I need to construct the triangle from those three points.
How to do it with vertex or geometry shaders?

Comment: You realize that there is an infinity of triangles you can create around a given point, right? What shape do you want the triangle, how do you want them oriented? What do you intend to do with this?

Comment: I would like to render a point cloud. For that, I need to create a primitive shape for each of the given points. I chose to show a triangle as the primitive shape. Yes, we can create many triangles for a given point. As a first step, I will hardcode the offsets to find the three vertices of the triangle.

Comment: Still trying to find the answer. Any info on this would be helpful.

Comment: That's not exactly what you need but I went through [something similar](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/186347/40264) in the past, maybe it could be of help, at least as a starting point.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Thanks for the help. But this is not what I'm expecting. I need to create a custom shader in Stride3d through which I need to alter the vertices. Whatever I do, the entity is not rendered in the scene.